# Font in Java AWT not rendered correctly when it's larger than 100 points

Tags: java, image, fonts, awt

I'm trying to render the text into an image using `JAVA` AWT. When I use a font smaller than 100 points, everything works as expected. But when I use, for example, 240 points, then some parts of the text that overlap are transparent like in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq3aO.jpg). In the sample image, I used this [font](https://www.1001fonts.com/autumn-in-november-font.html). I used this font in a text editor without any problem.

The font is loaded using this code:

```
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("src/main/resources/Autumn in November.ttf"));
Font derived = font.deriveFont(240f);
```

To render the text in the image I use this code:

```
 public static void saveTextToImage(String text, Font font) throws IOException {

        # Temp image to get the text dimensions
        BufferedImage tempImage = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D tempGraphics = tempImage.createGraphics();
        tempGraphics.setFont(font);
        FontMetrics fontMetrics = tempGraphics.getFontMetrics();
        FontRenderContext fontRenderContext = tempGraphics.getFontRenderContext();
        GlyphVector gv = font.createGlyphVector(fontRenderContext, text);
        Area area = new Area(gv.getOutline());
        Rectangle2D rectangle2D = area.getBounds2D();
        int width = (int) rectangle2D.getWidth();
        int height = (int) rectangle2D.getHeight();

        // Create a new image with white background
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D graphics = img.createGraphics();
        graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        // Draw the text on the image
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        graphics.setFont(font);
        graphics.drawString(text, 10, fontMetrics.getAscent() + 5);

        // Save the image
        File outputFile = new File(text + ".jpg");
        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", outputFile);
}
```

I've tried changing the font type to `OTF`, adding and changing `RenderingHints` and also switching the image type to `PNG`, but without success. I don't know what else I could try.

Comment: Which Java version? And why these unnecessary detours? `gv.getOutline()` returns a `Shape` so you could call `getBounds2D()` directly on it without copying it into an `Area`, but you could even call `gv.getVisualBounds()` in the first place. Well, in fact, you can query the sizes from the `fontMetrics` without constructing a `GlyphVector`. Letting the detours aside, you should calculate the sizes using the same rendering hints as when painting. And when you add constants like `10` and `5` to the coordinates afterwards, you have to adjust the image size accordingly.

Comment: One option is to create an image with your huge text font and use the image in your Java Swing project.

Comment: @Holger I tried 8, 11 and 17 with the same outcome. I agree with the detour, but using `GlyphVector` I am able to get more precise dimension of the text. The rendering hints does not change the issue with overlapping.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I need large number of these images, manually creating them is unfeasible.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the glyph rendering, using the wrong winding rule ("even-odd" instead of "non-zero"), see [Wikipedia: non-zero rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonzero-rule), especially the figure on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a strange behavior. I can’t tell you why this happens, but I can offer you a work-around; the problem does not occur when rendering the string’s glyphs one by one:

```java
static final boolean USE_WORKAROUND = true;

public static void saveTextToImage(String text, Font font) throws IOException {
    // Temp image to get the GlyphVector and text dimensions
    BufferedImage tempImage = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D tempGraphics = tempImage.createGraphics();
    tempGraphics.setFont(font);
    tempGraphics.setRenderingHint(
        RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    FontRenderContext fontRenderContext = tempGraphics.getFontRenderContext();
    GlyphVector gv = font.createGlyphVector(fontRenderContext, text);
    Rectangle2D rectangle2D = gv.getVisualBounds();
    int width = (int)(rectangle2D.getWidth());
    int height = (int)(rectangle2D.getHeight());

    // Create a new image with white background
    BufferedImage img
        = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D graphics = img.createGraphics();
    graphics.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    graphics.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    graphics.setRenderingHint(
        RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    // using GlyphVector avoids repeating the work already done above
    if(!USE_WORKAROUND) {
        graphics.drawGlyphVector(gv,
            (float)-rectangle2D.getX(), (float)-rectangle2D.getY());
    } else {
        graphics.translate(-rectangle2D.getX(), -rectangle2D.getY());
        for(int gix = 0, gnum = gv.getNumGlyphs(); gix < gnum; gix++) {
            graphics.fill(gv.getGlyphOutline(gix));
        }
    }

    // Save the image
    File outputFile = new File(text + ".jpg");
    ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", outputFile);
}
```

As a side note, I would use PNG instead of JPG as it is better suited for such images, but perhaps you don’t have this choice.

Further note that rendering an existing `GlyphVector` via `drawGlyphVector` has been documented to be “the fastest way to render a set of characters to the screen”, so if we have to perform this preparation work anyway for calculating the bounds, why not use it for the rendering…